# How to properly debug a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debugging

I am using the following code in a bash script in order to trace the code

```
#!/bin/bash
function trace()
{
    echo "TRACE" \
         "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}:${FUNCNAME[1]}:" \
         "$BASH_COMMAND"
}

set -o functrace
shopt -s extdebug
trap trace DEBUG

# Remainder of code here
exit 0
```

But when I run it, it eats my variables. 
Some clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/491897

Comment: http://bashdb.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: Duplicate? I think so, but the answers here are better…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is to use `set -xv`. The `set -v` will echo a line before it is executed. The `set -x` will output the line after the shell script interpolates the variables and expressions in that line.

As part of this, you can also create an environment variable called `PS4` which will be the prompt printed each time your shell scripts outputs the line being executed. Most people set it to something like `PS="\$LINENO: "` which will print out the line number for the line being executed.

Once you're finished, you can turn off debugging by setting `set +xv`.

```
#
# Somewhere in this part of my script, I am having problems....
#
export PS4="\$LINENO> "   # Now, I'll see the line numbers while debugging
set -xv                   # Debugging is turned on
....
#
# Done with debugging
#
set +xv                   # Debugging is turned off
```

Comment: Thx! You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few recommendations:

- You can always echo line in your shell script to see what's going on.
- You can also use `set -xv` to help you debug a shell script. Simply put `set -xv` before the part you want to debug, and `set +xv` to turn off the debug. You can also use `export PS4="\$LINENO> "` to print out the line number in your shell script.

Here's how your script will look with the `set -xv`. It's a really nice tool for debugging shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The following setup will enable printing of the line number and function name for each command (assuming you later put `set -x` in front of the code you're debugging):

```
set -o functrace
shopt -s extdebug
PS4='+ line ${LINENO-}, in ${FUNCNAME-}(): '
```

Here's some code to test the above:

```
foo() { echo "now in $FUNCNAME"; bar; }
bar() { echo "now in $FUNCNAME"; baz; }
baz() { echo "now in $FUNCNAME";      }

set -x
foo
```